# ASP.NET Mailing: Usage of SMTPClient.EnableSsl 

Tags: asp.net

Iam trying to send a mail using ASP.NET. When the `SMTPClinet.EnableSsl` is set to *true*, mail is receivable. However, if it is set to *false*, an error is thrown.

Can anyone help me in understanding its need.

Comment: error was " must issue STARTTLS  command  first"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because the *SMTP* server generally requires user authentication. And to transfer credential you must use a cryptography model which is in this case the *Secure Socket Layer* SSL. So, you need to activate SSL.

---

Refer to the following:

[SmtpClient.EnableSsl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It depends  on the smtp user you are using, ask your administrator about the right configuration including the port and either it requires SSL or not and the right username and password.